# Почему не могу сменить ОС?

Tags: linux, windows, manjaro

Всем привет!
Недавно решил перейти с винды на линукс,сначала попробовал ubuntu 20.04 LTS, потом через неделю пользования перешел на manjaro,выделил под него все место на дисках. Вчера понадобилось установить назад виндовс,но проблема в том,когда делаю загрузочную флешку,вот такая проблема
[image: введите сюда описание изображения].Возможно здесь есть люди которые лучше в этом разбираються,я же не знаю что делать.
Прошу не бросать камнями,с операционными системами не так давно работаю

Comment: "проблема в том,когда делаю загрузочную флешку,вот такая проблема" - опишите ситуацию (Что бы её можно было **воспроизвести**) и суть проблемы (что вас **не устраивает**?). 1) Что Вы "делаете" 2) Как Вы это делаете : на какой ОС, какой программой, последовательность Ваших действий... Телепатов тут нет...

Comment: попросил в друга ноутбук на виндовс 10,скачал файл iso с сайта microsoft с помощью программы rufus записал на флешку образ диска(файловая система на флешке была FAT32),когда с нее пытаюсь загрузиться на екране такая вот проблема как на скриншоте.

Comment: мы даже не знаем модель ноута и настройки биоса/uefi, а также, что именно Вы с ним делали. Может между делом перепрошили биос.

Comment: @ShevchukAndry "файл iso записал на флешку" Файлы типа ISO являются образом файловой системы CD. Писать их на флешку - ровно столько же смысла, как вешать стоп-сигнал на зайца. Если Вы хотите получить загрузочную **флешку**, то нужно эту флешку записать специальной программой. Подробности тут: https://lumpics.ru/programs-for-burning-an-image-on-a-usb-flash-drive/